# Timer strange behaviour

Tags: c#, timer

I have a Windows.Forms.Timer used in a form that works if I set its `Enabled` property to true in the properties window, and that is the only time it works. If I leave it disabled then enable it only when I need to, it doesn't tick.

```
        private void btnRename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerUpdateProgress.Enabled = true;
            timerUpdateProgress.Start();
            pbProgress.Maximum = clbFiles.CheckedItems.Count;
            var renameTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doRename(true, tbCurrentDirectory.Text, clbFiles.CheckedItems, rules));
            if(renameTask.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                timerUpdateProgress.Enabled = false;
                new ExceptionsWindow(renameTask.Result).ShowDialog();
            }
            timerUpdateProgress.Enabled = false;
            loadFiles(tbCurrentDirectory.Text);
        }

        private void timerUpdateProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbProgress.Value = progress; //I have a breakpoint on this line
        }
```

All I'm trying to do is display the progress of an operation with a progress bar. Enabling and starting the timer does nothing, the tick never happens. Why is this happening?

Update: stepping through the code after adding a sleep of 2000ms after enabling and starting the timer shows it still does not tick (I have a breakpoint in the tick handler).

More clarification: When the timer is enabled in the property window, the tick handler is always being called, and that's without calling `Start()`. My breakpoint is triggered all the time just by enabling the timer. I should also note that I'm using .NET 4.

Comment: what's the cause for disabling/enabling. Why not just stop/start as and when required?

Comment: What is the value in `progress`?? Is that updating?

Comment: It seems like you're not giving your Timer very much time to tick.  What is the interval you're using?  In your code above, the only time the timer will be running is for about 4-5 lines of code, which will be a couple of milliseconds maybe.

Comment: @DavidLloydBrookes they do the same thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @RobinMaben yes it is updating. @onemancat the `doRename` method is a loop, so it should have SOME time to do it, especially since it involves IO. Even then, I tried adding a `Thread.Sleep()` in there to give it time after enabling and starting it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LoganDam:Sorry for the silly question. Have you handled the timer tick event?? timerUpdateProgress.Tick += timerUpdateProgress_Tick;

Comment: @RameshDurai: It's already there - `timerUpdateProgress_Tick`.

Comment: @RameshDurai I let VS2010 do that for me, and I know it works because my breakpoint is triggered when I enable the timer in the property window.

Comment: @RameshDurai it's associated, that's why my breakpoint is triggered if the timer is enabled by default.

Comment: @LoganDam: Where is the part where you set `timerUpdateProgress.Enabled = true`??

Comment: Although it doesn't explain the problem as you're describing it, an immediate problem with your code is you're blocking the UI thread in `btnRename_Click` by immediately trying to fetch the `Result` property. Presumably `Timer` is *trying* to marshal back to the UI thread, but it's still stuck waiting for `btnRename_Click` to finish. Whether or not the timer is *trying* to tick, your button-click is blocking the UI thread, and that's going to cause issues.

Comment: RE: My above comment, I'd suggest looking at task continuations - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx or the async / await pattern - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx.

Comment: I'm in way over my head, so I ditched the progress bar and I'm just using a label to show progress now, in the form of "renaming/done".

Comment: In the end we all need to be pragmatic. One other construct you *might* consider, and can be a bit simpler to use if you're familiar with WinForm event programming is the BackgroundWorker - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
After getting an idea from the comments - it seems you **do not need the timer at all**.

You can update the progress bar `Value` as and when the value of `progress` is updated.

That way the transition from 0 - 100% might also seem smoother.

---

According to me you need disable the timer.

Just use

```
timer.Stop();
```

And then `timer.Start()` when needed again.

Additionally, if you have disabled timer progress, then you also **must do**

```
timerUpdateProgress.Enabled = true
```

Comment: Finally, some progress! (excuse the pun) I left the timer enabled in properties and then used `timerUpdateProgess.Stop()` in my form constructor after `InitializeComponents()`. Then when I click the button that starts the operation, I use `timerUpdateProgress.Start()`, then when the operation is done, I stop it again. That yielded some success, but it looks like the operation is still finishing before the timer can tick.

Comment: If the operation (sometimes) finishes before the timer ticks then you also need to update the progress bar then, not only on the timer tick event. I would not use the timer at all: instead update the bar wherever the code updates `progress` (looks like a class field). Should make things simpler.

Comment: Of course you can't update the progress bar on a non-UI thread, which I gather is created by `Task.Factory.StartNew`. If a worker thread is in control of progress updates, you will need to sync to the UI thread (use `Control.Invoke` and `Control.BeginInvoke` for this). And while we're on thread synchronisation, does your code sync reads/writes to the shared variable `progress`? If not there is a race condition.

Comment: That was what I had initially but I had the problem of accessing the UI from the non UI thread, and that's why I used the timer to try get around the issue.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is designed exactly for this scenario. Provided you don't mind your logic being tied to the System.Windows.Forms namespace, it's the simplest option - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How long did "Task.Factory.StartNew" take ? (If this is syncronous)

If above lambda expression is asyncronous, I see whether  renameTask.Result.Count is bigger than 0 or not, progress bar = false...

Comment: I have no idea if I'm honest. I don't really understand C# threading all that well, and this was recommended to me by SO and it works, so I've stuck with it. I come from Java where making a thread is as easy as implementing an interface.